# How do I make a good feature using machine learning on a timeseries forecast that has only traffic volume as an input?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, feature-engineering

So I have a time series that only has traffic volume. I've done FB prophet and neural prophet. They work okay, but I would like to do something using machine learning. So far I have the problem of trying to make my features. Using the classical dayofyear, month, etc does not give me good results. I have tried using shift where I get the average, minimum, and max of the two previous days. However that would work, but my problem is when I try to predict days in advance the feature doesn't really work for that since I cant get the average of that day. My main concern is trying to find a good feature that my predicting future dataframe also has. A picture of my data is included. Does anyone know how I would do this?
[image]

Comment: It seems like you don't have a lot of choices in here. You can bin your traffic volume, create a new feature from the region traffic volume intersections,  add a "time since start" feature.

Comment: have you tried Takens embedding ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takens%27s_theorem Basically, you represent each day with a vector of size d, where the first component is the day's value, the second is the value X days before, the third 2X days before, etc. Then you could use LSTM or transformers on the sequence of vectors to predict future values

Comment: Would you be able to show me an example of how to do this in python?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to clarify some definitions. FBProphet works on a mechanism that is the same as any machine learning algorithm that is, fitting the model and then predicting the output. Being an additive regression model with a piecewise linear or logistic growth curve trend, it can be considered as a Machine Learning method that allows us to predict a continuous outcome variable.

Secondly, I think you missed the most important word that your question was about - namely: Feature engineering.

Feature Engineering includes :

- Process of using domain knowledge to Extract features (characteristics, properties, attributes) from raw data.
- Process of transforming raw data into features that better represent the underlying problem to the predictive models, etc..

But it's very unlikely to use Machine Learning to do Feature engineering. You do Feature engineering in order to improve your Machine Learning model. Many techniques such as imputation, handling outliers, binning, log transform, one-hot encoding, grouping operations, feature split, scaling are hybrid methods using a statistical approach and/or domain knowledge.

Regarding your data, bearing in my mind that the seasonality is already handled by FBProphet, I am not confident if feature engineering transformations such as adding the day of the week, adding holidays periods, etc... could really help improve performance...

To conclude, it is not possible to create *ex-nihilo* new features that would outperform your model. Whether you process/transform your data or add external domain-knowledge dataset